# Symlinks in node.js on commit

Tags: svn, node.js, express, symlink

I was trying to create a node.js (express.js) app on a shared folder in VirtualBox (guest Ubuntu, host Win7). During this try I got an error saying symlinks are not supported by my drive.
This is a minor issue, but...

If symlinks are so important to node projects how it's possible to store the project on SVN service (which ignores symlinks). Or what happens if I ZIP the directory with the project and send it to someone. Will it still work?

It seems like a silly question, but I just got an error on creating an express.js project caused by symlinks-not-supported message.

Comment: Just in case someone missed this: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#symlinks

Comment: Yeah, but really what I want to achieve is to develop on windows (netbeans) and run on linux ^^ So I need to know whether those symlinks are essential or just used during the installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you were creating your express project nor how you came by the error, but I can tell you from experience that symlinks are not essential for node projects.

My usual development environment is Windows 7 and deploying to linux is just a simple matter of moving the files into the other environment either by packing them, using git or creating a nvm package or any other way.

Comment: As I said, I created the project on linux guest on shared directory (with windows). Do you have any problems with node on windows? I'd rather develop on Windows but I heard that there are some weird problems connected with it.

Comment: Haven't had any problems besides some modules not working due to compilation failures

Comment: I mark this response as an answer because it ensured me that my way is OK. Id est, I still work on shared directory in Ubuntu while files are on host Windows 7, but when I encounter any "symlinks" errors during module installation do I perform actions: (1) copy files to linux partition, (2) perform module installation, (3) copy files back to shared folder. Lucky modules ain't installed every day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to enable the creation of symlinks in VirtualBox use the following:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

Note that the SHARE_NAME should not include the sf_ part - just the name visible when you view it in the Shared Folders screen in the VirtualBox interface.

This will enable symlink creation from a guest.  However, it could open up a security issue.  You can read more about the problem on the VirtualBox site [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085%20here) and decide if it is the correct choice for your requirements. Another discussion of this solution for Windows users is  [here](http://ahtik.com/blog/2012/08/16/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/).